# How to remove recently viewed products in product page magento

Tags: magento

I want to remove the recently viewed products which are in the product page . and i have tried many times but not been able to find a solution . i have done some editing in the local.xml

but it didnot worked

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Open reports.xml of your theme template. (**app\design\frontend\theme\default\layout\reports.xml**)
There will be code like

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
```

Remove that, clear cache and Reload

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the related products block from `<catalog_product_view>` in your **catalog.xml** file:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Remove the block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and find the viewed products instruction in your store. And then, in **yout theme's** local.xml, use the correct handle to remove it from the wanted section.

For example, how to remove Magento's base theme default instruction in product view:

```
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </catalog_product_view>
```

The next example is how I removed it from my store, which was based on a different theme:

```
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="product.info.viewed" />
    <catalog_product_view>
```

Clear the cache and you're good to go!

This is the recommended way. You should avoid to duplicate or modify the original XML layout files. Always use your theme local.xml file instead.